# Excel: Getting #VALUE when using external links in an array user-defined-function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I created an user-defined-function that will return an array, and the inputs of the function are linked to another excel file. Whenever I update the formula without opening the external file, the formula returns #VALUE. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: please post your formula

Comment: Yes. Open the referenced file before recalculating your workbook. Some formulas only work when the external workbooks referred to are open.